# Show that τ is a stopping time with respect to FX

Tags: probability, stopping-times

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvLDp.png

Given the probability space in the attached image I would like to Show that τ is a stopping time with respect to FX.

I have calculated the FX to be:

F0X=σ({X0})=(ØΩ)

F1X= σ({X0,X1)}= σ({a,b},{c,d})

F2X= σ(X0,X1,X2})= σ({a},{b},{c},{d})=2Ω

and I know from here my next step would be to calculate  τ of each event. This is where I come unstuck as it appears that τ is actually 0,0,0,0 because at Time 0 the value is already above the stopping time of 10 therefore we never reach event 1 or 2. But if τ = 0 my understanding is it does not fit the criteria to be a stopping time. Excuse the beginner level question but can anyone help me work through this problem?

Many thanks

Comment: Please use MathJax in future, @Sam.U

Comment: Why do you think that $\tau=0$ is not a stopping time?